# Make button move up with ImageView on Iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I have an imageview that moves up when i click a button. i want the button to sit within the image view and move up with the view when i click the button, is there an easy way to 'attach' the button to the view in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design your xib like this

```
UIView
  UIView
     ImageView
  UIButton
```

or try if ImageView hide the button or else you can "Send to Back" imageView

```
UIView
  UIButton
  UIView
    ImageView
```

Comment: thanks for your reply control-v, ive tried arranging my view in this way but the button stays in the same position while the image view moves up. is there anything i would need to do with my code?